# relative cell reference indirect function

Tags: microsoft-excel

How should I change the following formula in order to make the range C6:C8 relative? So, for instance if the formula is copied to an adjecent cell I would like the C6:C8 range changed to D6:D8

=SOM(INDIRECT("'Data Sheet'!C6:C8"))

Thanks, Raul

Comment: Do you need the INDIRECT() included in your formula for a reason not stated here in the question?  At first glance it looks like you should just do the SUM without the INDIRECT, that way the copy/paste of the formula updates as expected when it's put in a new cell.

Comment: Can you add an example of what would be in the cells so it's easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish with the formula?

Comment: sorry, I should indeed have added more info for clarity. I want to be able to delete the worksheet 'Data Sheet' and replace it with an update version of the worksheet with the same name (Data Sheet). However, if I do this, the reference breaks. That is why I thought of using the INDIRECT function. I see that this works, only I cannot get the last part of the formula (C6:C8) to be relative. It seems I cannot get the syntax right. I tried things like =SOM(INDIRECT("'Data Sheet'!"&C6:C8)) but this gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar to the below, if you NEED to use indirect.
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Data Sheet1'!"&CELL("address",C7)&":"&CELL("address",C8)))

However as stated previously and judging by your description you could use:
=SUM('Data Sheet1'!C6:C8)